# Only load content of section if on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Technology used: Bootstrap 3.1.1, jQuery 1.11

Goal: I have a section where I'd only like to load the contents of it on mobile devices.

If I just used Bootstrap's visible-sm and hidden-lg classes, the content is still loaded on larger devices / sizes, creating overhead.

My section code is below. I'd like to only load & show the contents of it on a mobile device. I know the visible and hidden classes show & hide, but I want to only LOAD it on mobile devices - that's the key. No overhead.

```
<section id="category-icons" class="row visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="container White_BG">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Hand Tools" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/Handtools-cat-sprite.png"></a>         
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Field Production" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/Fieldproduction-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Pruning Tools" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/Pruning-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Material Handling" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/materialhandling-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Safety Equipment" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/safetyequipment-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Sprayers & Spreaders" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/sprayers-spreaders-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Watering & Irrigation" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/watering-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Marking & Tagging" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/markingtagging-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Herbicides & Pesticides" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/herbicides-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Greenhouse Production" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/greenhouse-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Fertilizers & Treatments" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/fertilizers-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Container Production" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/containerproduction-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Pest Control" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/pestcontrol-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Power Equipment" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/powerequipment-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Work Wear" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/workwear-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Turf & Landscape" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/turf-landscape-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Arborist Equipment" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/arborists-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Measuring & Surveying" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/measuring-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Maintenance Supplies" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/maintenance-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Snow Removal" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/snowremoval-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Used, Scratch, Dented Items" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/art/useditems-cat-sprite.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was downvoted. A simple jQuery plugin can do the trick:

```
(function(global, $) {

if (!global.matchMedia) {
    throw new Error("This browser does not support matchMedia()");
}

$.fn.lazyLoad = function(overrides) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.lazyLoad.defaults, overrides || {});

    this.find("[data-lazyload-url]").each(function() {
        var url = this.getAttribute("data-lazyload-url"),
            media = this.getAttribute("data-lazyload-media"),
            $target = $(this).addClass(options.loadingClass);

        if (!media || global.matchMedia(media)) {
            $.ajax(url)
            .done(function(data) {
                $target.html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                $target.html("Error: " + xhr.status);
            })
            .always(function() {
                $target.removeClass(options.loadingClass);
            });
        }
    });
};

$.fn.lazyLoad.defaults = {
    loadingClass: "loading"
};

})(this, jQuery);
```

And to use it:

```
$(document).lazyLoad();
```

Some sample HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-lazyload-url="/foo/bar">
        Load for every browser
    </div>
    <div data-lazyload-url="/baz" data-lazyload-media="screen and max-width: 500px">
        Load for 500px and smaller viewports
    </div>
</body>
```

This uses the latest version of jQuery, but I imagine the only changes you might need to make involve the call to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the html elements a default style display:none; and an id which returns in a JS mobile detect (actually handheld) script like:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $('#yourID').removeAttr('style');
}
```

Personally I would use a server side PHP class like Mobile Detect (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) and put the device type (whether it be a mobile device or tablet) in a session to use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

This code checks all possible mobile devices

```
var mobile = (function (b) {
    var a = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) return true;
})();

    if (mobile === true){
     // show mobile content here
     // example:
     $.ajax({
     url: "mobilecontent.html"
     }).done(function() {
       $('#mobilecontainer').html(data);
     });
}
```

Code slightly altered from [detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Comment: Ok, but how do I display content? Sorry, just not sure how that script works & such.

Comment: You haven't provided us with much info about how or what you want to load. Inside the if statement above, you could put whatever code you need to run when it's a mobile device. You could load an external html page / template with jQuery's ajax or whatever.

Comment: I'm looking to have the section be in my HTML, but load the entire contents of the container div only on mobile devices. That's literally it.

Comment: Then try something like the example above. Load the html page with ajax, insert the returned html to the right element in your page.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is to use a separate ajax request to load the particular content, only if the device happens to be a mobile device.

```
   if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    ...#Ajax request here to load the section content
   }
```

The second approach can be to handle this in the backend, if it is required. The request sent to the server can be used to obtain information about the user agent. In case of rails

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

is used to detect the user agent used. This can be used to compare with the mobile devices described above. The section content can be made to be rendered only if the request is from a mobile device.

```
<% if mobile? %>
 <section>
 </section>
<% end %>
```